# Inappropriate OGNL expression for hyphen (-)

Tags: java, exception, struts2, weblogic12c, ognl

I am passing Device name and Device Version in the Request parameters as **device-name** and **device-version** in Struts 2 application running in Weblogic12C application server.

Application is taking the values from request and working fine but **ognl InappropriateExpressionException** is printing continuously in server log.
Even after including **excludeParams** property as below

```
<interceptor-stack name="commonStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="timer"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="SessionInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        <interceptor-ref name="params">
         <param name="excludeParams">dojo..*,device-*</param>
        </Interceptor-ref>
</interceptor-stack>
```

And Exception I am getting is as follows

> Error setting expression 'device-version' with value
>   '[Ljava.lang.String;@1012dde9' ognl.InappropriateExpressionException:
>   Inappropriate OGNL expression: device - version
>           at ognl.SimpleNode.setValueBody(SimpleNode.java:312)
>           at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
>           at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
>           at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:737)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:218)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:187)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:174)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter(OgnlValueStack.java:152)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:318)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:230)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
>          at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at com.tcs.interceptors.SessionInterceptor.intercept(SessionInterceptor.java:134)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.TimerInterceptor.invokeUnderTiming(TimerInterceptor.java:135)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.TimerInterceptor.intercept(TimerInterceptor.java:122)
>           at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
>           at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
>           at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:544)
>           at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>           at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>           at com.tcs.common.filter.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:114)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
>           at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
>           at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
>           at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
>           at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
>           at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
>           at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
>           at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
>           at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
>           at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
>           at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
>           at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)